# Adding data into rows of next column

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, user-interface, razor

Basically I am creating a data grid that displays data from different tables in database.I am using ASP.NET MVC4 for this.
Following is how my part of my code looks:

```
<table class="myTable">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.sets)
        {
            <tr class="parent" data-level="0">
                <td>
                      @item.setName
                @* Here my logic would go*@
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

So after displaying the rows of name of sets,in the next column I would want to display the elements that belong to that set.So I wrote another for loop in `<td></td>` that would loop through the `Model.elements` and check if it belongs to that set and display it.But I am getting "Element td cannot be nested within element td " validation error.
So how can I add data into rows of the next column?

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic below the first end td tags instead. You can't put td tags inside other td tags; a series of sibling td tags make up a row.

If you want each separate piece of data in its own column:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.sets)
    {
        <tr class="parent" data-level="0">
            <td>
                  @item.setName
            </td>
            @foreach (var element in Model.elements)
            {
            <td>
                @*logic here*@
            </td>
            }
        </tr>
```

If you want all your content inside the same cell, then you want:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.sets)
        {
            <tr class="parent" data-level="0">
                 <td>
                      @item.setName
                </td>
                <td>
                @foreach (var element in Model.elements)
                {
                    @*logic here*@               
                }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Hi,I tried your first sample of code but I am getting an error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."